# How to cache JAXB context in Spring SOAP web service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jaxb

We profiled our spring soap web service through spring insight and new relic, more than 60% of the time is consumed in spring jars. We are guessing this is something to do with logging, jaxb context. we are exposing soap ws.

We also observed that some of the time is consumed by security header.

Can we cache JAXB context in Spring soap web service? OR
Any other pointer to improve spring soap web service performance?

Thanks for help.

Configuration details:-

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="policyConfiguration" value="/WEB-INF/securityPolicy.xml"/>
        <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list> 
                <ref bean="callbackHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>

<bean id="callbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="users">
        <props>
            </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<sws:static-wsdl id="employeeTransfer" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/employeeTransfer.wsdl" />
```

Comment: Instantiating a JAXBContext is very expensive operation in terms of execution time. You should define a Jaxb2Marshaller (in the OXM package in Spring 3.0+) bean with a singleton scope so this initialization is done only once in your application. Can you post your configuration to see how are doing it now?

Comment: *"more than 60% of the time is consumed in spring jars"* That isn't really telling much. Which parts is it hanging on and is it really slow or is it just 60% of 2ms? You should really be more specific in which parts are slow and what you want to optimize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. its taking 7 sec in total. However, our java code take around 1.5 sec. Rest 5.5 sec is spent in spring framework's classes. This is what we really like to profile or do something to optimize the time.

Comment: I don´t see any bean related to Spring in your config. Are do initializing the context by hand within the code? If so, please post the relevant snippets.